# In the context of prime numbers, what does $(p-1)/2$ signify

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm looking at some prime generation code which first tests $p$ for primality, then has the option to check $(p-1)/2$ for primality.  The code already tests $p$ directly (testing against some known primes and using Miller Rabin), but then has the option run those same tests on $(p-1)/2$.  What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yes, it is being tested for primality.  In fact, "safe" is the name of the argument in the code :)

Comment: In any case, it is not "an additional check to see if $p$ is actually prime." It's a separate check to see if $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is prime, which is apparently useful in some cryptographic applications.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, sorry, not a math wiz so sometimes hard to know what/how to ask the question, I'll gladly provide any info I can.  [Here](https://github.com/libtom/tomsfastmath/blob/7bfb9037355131c123c478bf4cf1b3a63570dbc3/src/numtheory/fp_prime_random_ex.c#L70) is the bit of code I'm looking at if that helps.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, ok, the application is RSA key generation so I guess I'll check on the Cryptography Exchange site.

Comment: Got my answer here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47729/safe-primes-in-rsa

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, :/  Ok, I didn't realize you were not happy with the wording of the question.  Thought it was clear that the "test" was for primality, and that the test vectors were $p$ and $(p-1)/2$.  I have updated the wording for future viewers.  Let me know if it is still not satisfactory and I'll try again.

Comment: Thanks for tracking down the answer, which I found interesting.

Comment: Huge safe primes are difficult to find , and also not needed for RSA. But if one does want to find one, this feature helps.